# How to get firestore instance with react-redux-firebase?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

authAction.js: Here firebase.set is not working neither firestore.set is working. If I'm including getFirestore then it says getFirestore is not a function. And if I'm doing in below way then it says permission denied.

firebase.set(`users/${createdUser.user.uid}`, { ...newUser })
How can I use set function of firestore here

```
export const registerUser = user => 
  async (dispatch, getState, getFirebase) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    // const firestore = getFirestore();
    try {
      let createdUser = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      console.log('createdUser', createdUser);
      await createdUser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: user.displayName
      });
      let newUser = {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }
      console.log('new user', newUser);
      await firebase.set(`users/${createdUser.user.uid}`, { ...newUser })
      dispatch(closeModal())
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseConfig = {}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { devToolsEnhancer, composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from "../reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import firebase from '../config/firebase';

//react redux firebase config
export const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  attachAuthIsReady: true,
  useFirestoreForProfile: true
}

/*
########section without applyMiddleware(thunk)##########
*/

// export const configureStore = () => {
//   const store = createStore(rootReducer, devToolsEnhancer());
//   return store;
// }  


/*
########section with applyMiddleware(thunk)##########
*/
export const configureStore = () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)];

  const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    // reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
    // reduxFirestore(firebase)
  );

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer)

  return store
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'react-redux-toastr/lib/css/react-redux-toastr.min.css';
import App from './app/layout/App';
import ReduxToastr from 'react-redux-toastr';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore, rrfConfig } from './app/store/configureStore';
import ScrollToTop from './app/common/util/ScrollToTop';
import firebase from '../src/app/config/firebase';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider
      firebase={firebase}
      config={rrfConfig}
      dispatch={store.dispatch}
      createFirestoreInstance={createFirestoreInstance}
    >
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop>
          <ReduxToastr
            position='bottom-right'
            transitionIn='fadeIn'
            transitionOut='fadeOut'
          />
          <App />
        </ScrollToTop>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
export const registerUser = user => 
  async (dispatch, getState, getFirebase) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();  // <===
    try {
      let createdUser = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      console.log('createdUser', createdUser);
      /*await createdUser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: user.displayName
      });*/
      let newUser = {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      }
      console.log('new user', newUser);
      await firestore.collection("users").doc(createdUser.user.uid).set({ ...newUser }); // <===
      dispatch(closeModal())
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }
```

But since you included `userProfile: 'users'` in your rrfConfig, updateProfile is already doing what you are trying to do I think. So this would be the same result, and you don't need the firestore instance:

```
export const registerUser = user => 
  async (dispatch, getState, getFirebase) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    try {
      let createdUser = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      console.log('createdUser', createdUser);
      // updateProfile adds these to the correct users document
      await firebase.updateProfile({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      });
      dispatch(closeModal())
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you please be more descriptive? `firebase.firestore();` seem to be called in `firebase.js`. The question is well formatted and it would be great if you could help the author to understand how to fix the issue by adjusting the code provided

Comment: I edited my answer with more code, hope it helps and works for you